# Type error: Unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'Str':

Tags: python

I am trying to build something I cloned from Github and I get the error

```
Type error: Unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'Str
```

I've opened up the related file and I assume the problem is the `+` in the code below. Please could someone tell me what I should change this to so that it will successfully build?

```
GCC_VERSION = re.split('\.', commands.getoutput(env['CXX'] + ' -dumpversion'))
```

Many Thanks

Comment: Is the gcc installed on your box?

Comment: Read the error message again. What do you think it means? What debugging did you do? Presumably you looked at the values in the expression that fails. If you did not do that, why not?

Comment: I'm having trouble installing gcc. It says it has unmet dependencies. gcc-4.8 depends binutils (>=2.23.90.20131017) but 2.24.52.20130913 0ubuntu1 is to be installed.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `env['CXX']` isn't set.

Try running

```
export CXX=g++
```

before running the build